# Как запустить две функции в одном событии (onclick)?

Tags: php, javascript, html

В верхней части сайта есть поиск, в нижней - таблица, в которой должны выводиться данные о результате, по которому кликнет юзер. После нажатия кнопки, поиск, допустим, вывел 3 результата:

> 1. Имя: Василий, Фамилия: Пупкин.
> 2. Имя: Дмитрий, Фамилия: Соколов.
> 3. Имя: Иван, Фамилия: Иванов.

Например, пользователь кликает на первый результат. Все данные элемента должны вывестись в таблицу(которую я описывал выше).

HTML:

```
<div class="f_result">
    <h5>Имя</h5>
    <p id="name">_</p>
</div>
<div class="s_result">
    <h5>Фамилия</h5>
    <p id="surname">_</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function cock(n1) {
    document.getElementById('name').textContent = n1;
}
function cock1(n2) {
    document.getElementById('surname').textContent = n2;
}
```

PHP:

```
echo '<div onclick=n1("' . $row['user_name'] . '"); n2("' . $row['user_surname'] . '");>
        <p>Имя: ' . $row['user_name'] . '</p>
        <p>Фамилия: ' . $row['user_surname'] . '</p>
    </div>';
```

И всё бы ничего, но в таблицу выводится только имя. Кто знает решение?

Comment: Создать одну функцию **nFull(name, surname)** с двумя параметрами и внутри функции выполнять обновление text'a для обоих элементов. И у Вас, случаем, нет ошибки в вопросе в блоке PHP? _onclick=n1(param)_ - это точно? может должно быть _onclick=cock1(param)_

Comment: Я вижу, что Вы пишете комментарий, но когда захожу его прочесть, то он уже удален. Несмотря на то, что Вы приняли мой ответ ниже, хочу уточнить, все ли работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

PHP:

```
echo '<div onclick=nFull("' . $row['user_name'] . '","' . $row['user_surname'] . '");>
        <p>Имя: ' . $row['user_name'] . '</p>
        <p>Фамилия: ' . $row['user_surname'] . '</p>
    </div>';
```

JS:

```
function nFull(name, surname) {
    document.getElementById('name').textContent = name;
    document.getElementById('surname').textContent = surname;
}
```

Ну и почему-то отдельно захотелось прикрепить в ответ [линку](https://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/) на различие между textContent и innerText. Авось пригодится.